# How to remove index.php using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently building a PHP-based portfolio site without any frameworks whatsoever. I have created an `index.php` file in the root and a lot of folders namely `/about`, `/contact`, `/portfolio` and the like. Within each of those, I have a separate `index.php` file

I created a `.htaccess` file and in it, I have this code...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

For some reason when I visit my site at `example.com/index.php` or `example.com/about/index.php` the `.htaccess` file is not working and removing it.

Any ideas why?

Comment: You mean that the htaccess file is working and that's because it gets deleted. The condition written has a hit on all URL that end with index.php

Comment: Nope it's not working what I want to happen is to have the index.php removed at the end of all directories as well as the one in the root

Comment: AH it's not removing? That was not clear to me :)

Comment: Nope, not at all. even on the homepage for some reason.

Comment: The RewriteConds are all joined by an implicit AND. Since the `index.php` files physically exist, your second condition with the `-f` flag will fail for those.

Comment: But if you want to "remove" something from the URL shown in the browser address bar, then you need an external rewrite to begin with, which so far you have not implemented at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
> ```

If the intention with these directives is to *remove* `index.php` from the requested URL then you are using the wrong rules! This rule would route a request for `/something` to `index.php/something` (passing the requested URL-path as path-info to `index.php`) providing `/something` does not map to a file or directory.

You have presumably structured your URLs so they map to filesystem directories from which the `DirectoryIndex` is served, so the above directives would seem to be entirely redundant. (?)

---

#### To remove `index.php` from the end of any URL

To remove `index.php` (the `DirectoryIndex`) from any URL you would need to do something like the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

To clarify...

- you must not be linking internally to `/index.php` or `/about/index.php`. The above directive is only for when a user or external site erroneously requests the `index.php` file directly.
- And include trailing slashes on your internal links. eg. you should be internally linking to `/about/` and `/contact/` etc. (not `/about` or `/contact`), otherwise mod_dir will implicitly issue a 301 redirect to append the trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

It took a while and thanks for the suggestions by Mr White this is my solution..

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Works perfectly now.
Thank you for everyone who took the time out to help me on this.